# Put a form on every page of a website with Zend Framework 1

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework, web

it may seem like a dumb question because I feel like it is when asking it but I can't find anything about it in the doc.

I need to put a form in the header of my website that appears in all pages.
I need that form to be able to be submitted in every page (no surprise here).

I can display my form via the layout function of Zend Framework, but I can't find the equivalent for the back-end of the website to be able to treat it at only one place, site-wide.

I thought it would be possible to put the form validation in the bootstrap but it doesn't seem like it.

Did I miss something or do I have to, at least, put the form validation in all init()  function of all my controllers ?

Comment: Well the form does have an action attribute, I don't see what's the problem

Comment: When you specify an action other than the current page, you get redirected to that page before the validation, meaning that if you enter something wrong, you don't get the error message on the page you come from, but on the page you are after redirection, which isn't something desired in that case.

Comment: Having validation on the client side may be something you desire but is really something you should avoid

Comment: I don't have, nor want, validation client side, I don't really know why you'd think that. I'm just wondering if there's a way to simply put a form everywhere on a site natively with Zend, that gets validated in the current controller, then redirected to the wanted controller if it passes validation.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm confused. How is it that you can't just submit the form to a handler page that will then redirect the user to where you want them to go or return them to the page they came from with an error message :? Of course xhr will likely be pleasant in this case eliminating redundant redirects and what not

Comment: I'd like to avoid useless redirects because it's not really pleasant, that's why I'm looking for a way to do it without them :-)

Comment: Well have you not had any experience with xmlhttp requests?

Comment: I would put all validation and other stuff in helper (or plugin) and call it in layout. Probably there are better ways but this should work.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at the [plugin documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.plugins.html)

You can write a plugin that handles your request. If you need to have your form processed before any other actions take place, I suggest you use the dispatchLoopStartup() hook.

You should avoid predispatch and postdispatch in this case, because those hooks are called multiple times if you proces multiple actions (by using _forward for instance)